# MySQL ODBC Driver not recognizing date fields with DbFactory

Tags: c#, mysql, odbc, dbconnection

I have a date field stored just fine in MySQL:

[image]

But when I try to connect to it using the Microsoft ODBC driver, I get the following error:

> ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.7.19-log]Incorrect date value: '3/22/2013 12:00:00 AM' for column 'newdate' at row 1

This seems to be an issue with the ODBC driver.  I'm using `MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver`.

Anyone else encountered this error?

Update: Here is the c# code that generates this error:

```
DbCommand command = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.Odbc").CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _newTable AS SELECT * FROM `"  
    + tableName +"`";
command.Connection = TheDB.TheConn;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: WHEN is this error occuring? BY selecting, updating or inserting data? From other ODBC-Driver I know there are some options in the ODBC administrator configuring the connection, perhaps that helps.

Comment: This happens when trying to execute a `DbConnection` `CREATE TABLE ` command...

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE command, which you are sending via ODBC?